# passing in vector of dataframes in function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to build a function that accepts many dataframes and concatenates them into a single dataframe.  I'm trying to understand the recent update to dplyr or purrr? and how I would be able to do this.  I tried using the triple exclamtion points !!! inside my function but I'm still struggling to get this right...

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 = mtcars %>% slice(1:2)
df_2 = mtcars %>% slice(6:8)
df_3 = mtcars %>% slice(30:32)

get_bind_dfs = function(one_or_more_dfs ){

result = dplyr::bind_rows(one_or_more_dfs)
return(result)

}

get_bind_dfs(one_or_more_dfs = c(df1, df2, df3))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can pass a `vector` of strings and then use `mget` to get the values

```
get_bind_dfs <- function(str1 ){

  dplyr::bind_rows(mget(str1, envir = .GlobalEnv))

  }

get_bind_dfs(paste0("df_", 1:3))
# A tibble: 8 x 11
#    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  21.0  6.00   160 110    3.90  2.62  16.5  0     1.00  4.00  4.00
#2  21.0  6.00   160 110    3.90  2.88  17.0  0     1.00  4.00  4.00
#3  18.1  6.00   225 105    2.76  3.46  20.2  1.00  0     3.00  1.00
#4  14.3  8.00   360 245    3.21  3.57  15.8  0     0     3.00  4.00
#5  24.4  4.00   147  62.0  3.69  3.19  20.0  1.00  0     4.00  2.00
#6  19.7  6.00   145 175    3.62  2.77  15.5  0     1.00  5.00  6.00
#7  15.0  8.00   301 335    3.54  3.57  14.6  0     1.00  5.00  8.00
#8  21.4  4.00   121 109    4.11  2.78  18.6  1.00  1.00  4.00  2.00
```

---

Or pass the data.frames as a `list` which `bind_rows` can accept

```
get_bind_dfs <- function(one_or_more_dfs){

        dplyr::bind_rows(one_or_more_dfs)

 }

get_bind_dfs(list(df_1, df_2, df_3))
# A tibble: 8 x 11
#    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  21.0  6.00   160 110    3.90  2.62  16.5  0     1.00  4.00  4.00
#2  21.0  6.00   160 110    3.90  2.88  17.0  0     1.00  4.00  4.00
#3  18.1  6.00   225 105    2.76  3.46  20.2  1.00  0     3.00  1.00
#4  14.3  8.00   360 245    3.21  3.57  15.8  0     0     3.00  4.00
#5  24.4  4.00   147  62.0  3.69  3.19  20.0  1.00  0     4.00  2.00
#6  19.7  6.00   145 175    3.62  2.77  15.5  0     1.00  5.00  6.00
#7  15.0  8.00   301 335    3.54  3.57  14.6  0     1.00  5.00  8.00
#8  21.4  4.00   121 109    4.11  2.78  18.6  1.00  1.00  4.00  2.00
```

---

Or another option would be to use three dots as argument and then evaluate by converting to `quosures`

```
library(purrr)
get_bind_dfs <- function(...) {

   exprs <- rlang::enquos(...)
   map(exprs, rlang::eval_tidy) %>%
        bind_rows

  }

get_bind_dfs(df_1, df_2, df_3)
# A tibble: 8 x 11
#    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1  21.0  6.00   160 110    3.90  2.62  16.5  0     1.00  4.00  4.00
#2  21.0  6.00   160 110    3.90  2.88  17.0  0     1.00  4.00  4.00
#3  18.1  6.00   225 105    2.76  3.46  20.2  1.00  0     3.00  1.00
#4  14.3  8.00   360 245    3.21  3.57  15.8  0     0     3.00  4.00
#5  24.4  4.00   147  62.0  3.69  3.19  20.0  1.00  0     4.00  2.00
#6  19.7  6.00   145 175    3.62  2.77  15.5  0     1.00  5.00  6.00
#7  15.0  8.00   301 335    3.54  3.57  14.6  0     1.00  5.00  8.00
#8  21.4  4.00   121 109    4.11  2.78  18.6  1.00  1.00  4.00  2.00
```

---

When we do concatenate (`c`) of multiple `data.frame` (which is a `list` of columns), it loses the `data.frame` attribute and would append the columns in a `list`

```
c(df_1, df_2)
```